# Automatically upgrade Amazon AWS from micro to Medium

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a website at AWS ec2 micro instance. Is it possible to configure the autoscaling with storage space go up when needed and also the cpus or not? Thank you for any help and suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, AWS doesn't have vertical auto-scaling functionality for EC2 so this cannot be achieved without shutting down the instance and relaunching it as another (bigger) instance type. Horizontal scaling is, however, quite easy to configure (launching another copy of your instance with same instance type).

As a workaround, you can create a snapshot of your instance and use it to relaunch this instance as a bigger type (using CloudWatch, as @Sri.U pointed out in the comments).

The only instances which allow vertical scaling are RDS (relational database service) instances.

Comment: you may do automatically as well by setting a cloudwatch alarm and actions to it. see: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingAlarmActions.html